# Internet connection issues

Tags: wireless, internet-connection

I am running 11.10 and having issues getting (and maintaining) wireless connections.

I've been able to gain access when I've first turned on my computer in the past, but it will cut out after a short time and I won't be able to log back on. If I wake my computer from sleep mode, it won't be able to connect at all.

What is now worse, is I recently connected directly to the internet with a wired connection. That worked for a short period of time but I just tried to connect using it again and now it seems that it too isn't working.

I am new to Linux, and am not a programmer, so I apologize as you may have to simplify your answers for me - but I do know where terminal is...

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Is it sure that your Wireless / Router device is working well?  If your IP is automatic and Wireless Router device works well then:
1) Give reset to your device (hardware one and reconfigure it again from the beginning)
2) Click your network icon >> Disconnect wired and wireless connections on your pc
3) Right click your network icon >> Edit Connections...

on Tab [ Wired ] click on connection and then on right side click on button Delete.
on Tab [ Wireless ] right click on connection and then on right side click on button Delete.
(Delete all connections and turn off your router).

Restart your PC!
Let your device off, and after your system is on, switch off your wireless key, turn on your device and connect your wire cable. A new connection is going to be created automatically. Now test it going online. If it is OK then restart your PC and disconnect wire cable and switch on wireless key of your notebook. After detect your wireless connection, click on network icon, click on your connection and test your notebook by going online. ( I guess this is going to solve your problem ).

Anyway, you may control if your system is well configured by booting your notebook with Ubuntu live CD and connect to the wireless. Stay connected and if it is OK than the problem is at your system configuration.